# How to create relationship between entities & ApplicationUser in MVC 5 EF

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

If I have a `SharedDocument` entity with two properties I want to be related to my `ApplicationUser` entity, how do I do this?

On this [MS Tutorial](https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application), see if you name the property the same as the PK of the table you want to relate EF can find the relationship pretty easily. But I have two properties, `CreatedBy` & `ModifiedBy` that I want related to my `User` table but I do not want to name them `AspNetUserId`. How can I do this?

**Model**

```
 public class SharedDocumentModel : DbContext
 {        
    public SharedDocumentModel()
        : base("MyContext")
    {

    }        

    public virtual DbSet<SharedDocument> PortalDocuments { get; set; }
 }

 public class SharedDocument
 {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime Modified { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser ModifiedBy { get; set; }
    public string ContentType { get; set; }
    public string FileType { get; set; }
    public byte[] FileContent { get; set; }
    public double Version { get; set; }
 }
}
```

**Error on creating View with Model SharedDocuments**

```
There was an error running the selected code generator: 
'Unable to retrieve metadata for 
'MVC.WebSite.Models.SharedDocument'. One or more validation 
errors 'mere detected during model generation: 
MVC.WebSite.DAL.IdentityUserLogin: EntityType 'IdentityUserLogin' 
has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType. 
MVC.WebSite.DAL.IdentityUserRoIe: EntityType 'IdentityUserRoIe' has 
no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType. 
IdentityUserLogins: EntityType: EntitySet 'IdentityUserLogins' is based 
on Vpe 'IdentityUserLogin' that has no keys defined. 
IdentityUserRoles: EntityType: EntitySet 'IdentityUserRoles' is based on 
type 'IdentityUserRole' that has no keys defined.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by adding [ForeignKey](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.foreignkeyattribute(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
[ForeignKey("CreatedById")]
[ForeignKey("ModifiedById")]
```

So in you case:

```
public class SharedDocument
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("CreatedById")]
    public virtual ApplicationUser CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public string CreatedById { get; set; }
    public DateTime Modified { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ModifiedById")]
    public virtual ApplicationUser ModifiedBy { get; set; }
    public string ModifiedById { get; set; }
    public string ContentType { get; set; }
    public string FileType { get; set; }
    public byte[] FileContent { get; set; }
    public double Version { get; set; }
}
```

One more thing:
Merge your `DbContext` with `ApplicationDbContext` and use one database:

```
 public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        // Add custom user claims here
        return userIdentity;
    }
}

public class SharedDocumentModel : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public SharedDocumentModel()
        : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }
    public virtual DbSet<SharedDocument> PortalDocuments { get; set; }
    public static SharedDocumentModel Create()
    {
        return new SharedDocumentModel();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error message may be related to referencing ApplicationUser because it is in the `IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>` context. You can either setup your app context to inherit from the `IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>`, otherwise you will need to setup a copy of `DbSet<ApplicationUser>` in your SharedDocumentModel context.

Answer (score 0):

You must match name of FK with property name not property type. So if you have a property with type `User` and name `CreatedBy` your FK property must `CreatedByID` not `UserID`. Therefore you could simply Add following 2 properties to your `SharedDocument` class.

```
public class SharedDocument
{
    public string CreatedByID { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser CreatedBy { get; set; }

    public string ModifiedByID { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser ModifiedBy { get; set; }
    // rest of your code
}
```

As you can see the type of FK properties are `string` since type of `ApplicationUser`'s PK is `string` also.

But another important issue, it seems you are using Identity's default configuration. If so you already have a `DbContext` on your project named `ApplicationDbContext`. Find it and add your other Entities to it. Don't implement new `DbContext`.

```
// This class already added to your project
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    // This context already had ApplicationUser set you don't need to add it again
    // add your own new entities 
    public DbSet<SharedDocument> PortalDocuments { get; set; }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
}
```

At the end keep in mind to configuring EF you have 3 option:

1) Configuration by conventions, as I have done above.

2) Configuration by Data Annotation. By Adding Attribute to Properties or clasees:

```
[ForeignKey("CreatedById")]
public virtual ApplicationUser CreatedBy { get; set; }
```

3) Or by fluent API:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<SharedDocument>()
            .HasRequired(e => e.CreatedBy)
            .WithMany()
            .Map(e => e.MapKey("CreatedByID"));

        modelBuilder.Entity<SharedDocument>()
            .HasRequired(e => e.ModifiedBy)
            .WithMany()
            .Map(e => e.MapKey("ModifiedByID"));
    }
    // rest of code same as before
}
```